# angular2 set parent to undefined

Tags: typescript, angular

I want to display a row depending on a user hits "edit" and hide the row if the user cancels the "edit". 
Problem is, my edit component is hidden but the row not.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        &nbsp;
        <div class="form-group form-inline">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" (click)="initEditAufwand(aufwand)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> edit
            </button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr *ngIf="aufwand == selectedAufwand">
    <td colspan="7">
        <aufwand-eingabe [aufwand]="selectedAufwand"></aufwand-eingabe>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Component Template:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Abbrechen" (click)="cancelAufwand()" />
```

Component:

```
export class AufwandEingabeComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    aufwand: Aufwand;
    ngOnInit() {
        //TODO Task laden
    }

    cancelAufwand() {
        this.aufwand = undefined;
    }

}
```

if i change a value in "AufwandEingabeComponent" it gets updated in the parent Table so this works, but setting undefined does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two-way-binding you need `@Input()` **and** `@Output()`.

two-way-binding syntax in HTML

```
<aufwand-eingabe [(aufwand)]="selectedAufwand"></aufwand-eingabe>
```

note the added `(...)`.

- `[aufwand]="parentField"` is for downward binding, from parent to child
- `(aufwandChange)="parentField = $event"` is for upwards binding, from child to parent
- `[aufwand]="parentField" (aufwandChange)="parentField = $event"`
  or the shorthand form `[(aufwand)]=parentField` is for two-way-binding

```
export class AufwandEingabeComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    aufwand: Aufwand;

    @Output() aufwandChange:EventEmitter<Aufwand> = new EventEmitter<Aufwand>();

    ngOnInit() {
        //TODO Task laden
    }

    cancelAufwand() {
        this.aufwandChange.emit(undefined);
    }
}
```

The `@Output() aufwandChange:EventEmitter<Aufwand>` is necessary for upwards binding `(aufwandChange)` and `this.aufwandChange.emit(someValue)` passes `someValue` to be forwarded to the parent.

Comment: sounds good but now inside my Component *ngIf="aufwand" is always false

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code of your component.

Comment: <div class="panel panel-default" *ngIf="aufwand">
Component is "aufwandEingabeComponent"

Comment: `<aufwand-eingabe [(aufwand)]="selectedAufwand"></aufwand-eingabe>` binds to `selectedAufwand` in the parent component. `aufwand` is the name of the field in the child component (`AufwandEingabeComponent`). Perhaps you want to use `<aufwand-eingabe [(aufwand)]="aufwand"></aufwand-eingabe>` instead.